# Buddhist deities that help transmute bad qualities into good ones

Tags: philosophy

I remember reading many years ago about Buddhist deities who help their devotees transmute their bad qualities into good ones.

In particular, I remember reading that one of the Buddhas (possibly the Amitabha Buddha) helps transform envy into achievement.

Is there any Buddhist literature/practice on these lines?